# Expanding wildcard in echo to file

Tags: bash, wildcard-expansion

Say I have the following in Bash:

```
FOO=/a/c*/d/
echo PATH=${FOO}:${PATH} >> .env
```

When I inspect the contents of the file `.env` the path still contains the wildcard. How can I ensure that the wildcard is expanded to the path, assuming there is only one match, so that the wildcard does not exist in the file when echoed?

Answer (score 2):

Make it an array assignment, and then use the first element of the array (to hold with the "assuming only one match"):

```
foo=( /a/c*/d/ )
echo "PATH=${foo[0]}:$PATH" >>.env
```

By contrast, if you don't specifically want the assumption, you can use `${array[*]}` after setting `:` as the first character in `IFS` to expand correctly even in the case where there were multiple matches:

```
foo=( /a/c*/d/ )
IFS=:
echo "PATH=${foo[*]}:$PATH" >>.env
```

You could avoid needing to change `IFS` or pay the efficiency cost of starting a subprocess by expanding the list of paths to a separate variable:

```
printf -v path_prefix '%s:' /a/c*/d/
echo "PATH=${path_prefix}$PATH" >>.env
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps also

```
foo=( /a/c*/d/ )
echo "PATH=$(IFS=:; echo "${foo[*]}"):$PATH" >> .env
```

so you don't have to restore `IFS`

Comment: There's an efficiency hit for the subshell that's worth pointing out -- sure, it's more work to need to restore IFS, but one gets some value for that work.

Comment: And if you _are_ going to have a subshell, you don't need an array at all. `echo "PATH=$(printf '%s:' /a/c*/d/)$PATH"` and you're done. Has the added benefit that if you `shopt -s nullglob` and there are no matches to the glob expression, the PATH doesn't get changed at all.

Comment: Good point about `printf` instead of array.